# Spring: @DateTimeFormat ignored in nested Objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

in my example the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation is ignored, when nesting objects:

```
class Person {
    private Date birthdate;
    // other fields

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy")
    public Date getBirthdate(){
       return birthdate;
    }
    // Other getters/setters 
}
```

And I have a class which nests this objects.

```
class PersonGroup {
    private Person person1;
    private Person person2;
    // other fields

    @Valid
    public Person getPerson1(){
       return person1;
    }

    // also tried without @Valid-Annotation
    public Person getPerson2(){
       return person2;
    }
    // Other getters/setters 
}
```

I add an object of the type `PersonGroup` to my model in a `@Controler`-Method like this:

```
model.addAttribute("myGroup", filledPersonGroup);
```

In an JSP I use print the nested variables:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myGroup" action="..." >
    <form:input path="person1.birthdate" >
    <form:input path="person2.birthdate" >
    ...
</form:form >
```

But unfortunately the date-values in the input-fields are not formatted correctly (but the date is shown in principle.).
It works, when I directly add an instance of the class `Person` to the model.

Can anybody tell me how I can handle this? I want the date of my nested objects be formatted correctly.

I use `Spring 4.1.1-RELEASE`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried annotating the field rather than the method?

```
class Person {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy")
    private Date birthdate;
     // other fields

    public Date getBirthdate(){
       return birthdate;
    }
    // Other getters/setters 
}
```